# Select the first element of a class, but not its children

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm working on a navigation bar. One of my navigation items has a dropdown. For this item, I want to disable the normal link behavior (I have already done this with jQuery) and just have it open a dropdown with three functioning links on hover.

All of this is working functionally, but I have some trouble with the styling.

Note that I'm using a CMS that automatically generates the navigation, so I can't use an `id` to target the relevant menu item.

My menu looks like this:

```
<ul class="header-navigation-list">
    <li class="header-navigation-list-item">
        <a class="header-navigation-link primary-link" href="...">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="header-navigation-list-item">
        <a class="header-navigation-link primary-link" href="...">About</a>
    </li>
    <li class="header-navigation-list-item has-dropdown">
        <a class="header-navigation-link primary-link" href="...">Products</a>
        <ul class="header-navigation-list secondary-list" data-is-dropdown>
            <li class="header-navigation-list-item secondary-list-item">
                <a class="header-navigation-link secondary-link" href="...">Product #1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="header-navigation-list-item secondary-list-item">
                <a class="header-navigation-link secondary-link" href="...">Product #2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="header-navigation-list-item secondary-list-item">
                <a class="header-navigation-link secondary-link" href="...">Product #3</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="header-navigation-list-item">
        <a class="header-navigation-link primary-link" href="...">Blog</a>
    </li>
    <li class="header-navigation-list-item">
        <a class="header-navigation-link primary-link" href="...">Contact</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The goal is to remove all link-styling from "Products", but keep the link styling for "Products #1 - #3".

I tried targeting it via several CSS rules like `.header-navigation-list > .has-dropdown` or `.header-navigation-list > .has-dropdown:first-of-type` or `.header-navigation-list > .has-dropdown a:first-child`. The problem is that every time I manage to target the "Products" point, I also target all the elements it contains and disable the link-styling for "Product #1 - #3" too.

Comment: can you please add your working css code?

Comment: try something like this:

    `ul.header-navigation-list:not(.secondary-list) > li:nth-child(3) > a {
    border: 1px solid red;
   }`

Answer (score 0):

### General recommendation

A general thumbrule when writing CSS selectors is to keep the amount of rules at a resonable level for several reasons:

- **Readability**: one should be able to understand what the class does by reading its name
- **Unified language** between team members. Everybody knows what to expect from a class.
- **Maintainable code**: your selectors do not unexpectadly break the website at an unknown place .

A good way to do this is by using the [BEM naming convention](http://getbem.com/naming/)

### Your case

However, since you do not seem to be in the position to decide what classes or ids you use, you have to work with what you have.

This solution is very general:

```
.has-dropdown > .primary-link{
    /*Reset styles goes here*/
}
```

It selects all elments where the direct children of  `.has-dropdown` is the `.primary-link` class. For more information see [Mozillas documentation on relationship selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors#Information_Selectors_based_on_relationships).

#### More specific CSS selectors

One example using the [:nth-child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) could be:

```
.header-navigation-list > .has-dropdown:nth-child(3) > .primary-link{
  /*CSS rules*/      
}
```

**THIS IS HOWEVER BAD PRACTICE** due to readability problems.

### Short summary

Whenever possible, choose your own classes, preferably according to a naming convention. If working with a CMS you might want to edit any theme files, but unless you plan to provide support for a long time, I would not recommend it.

Try to fully understand how to use CSS selectors and pseudo-selectors, to know what elements the styles will be applied to.

Comment: "A general thumbrule when writing CSS selectors is to keep the selectors as specific as possible. " -1. These are slower when rendering.

Comment: You say keep the number of rules to a minimum, and then recommend BEM. These two are contradictory. BEM writes new rules for every single element in every single block along with additional rules for every single modifier.

Comment: @Mooseman What was the last time you experienced slow rendering due to CSS? It should be, "a general rule of thumb when writing CSS selectors is to make them logical and clear and well-structured".

Comment: There we go, I rewrote most of it.

Answer (score 0):

The second example below might be what you're looking for (*jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pk8gsh9z/*):

```
/**
 * Example 1
 *
 * Targets the direct links of top-most LIs when all of the following are true:
 * - they have a "has-dropdown" class.
 * - they don't have a "secondary-list-item" class.
 */
.header-navigation-list .has-dropdown:not(.secondary-list-item) > a {
  color: brown;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

/**
 * Example 2
 *
 * Targets the direct links of the third LI when all of the following are true:
 * - it has the "has-dropdown" class
 * - and it doesn't have "secondary-list-item" class
 */
.header-navigation-list .has-dropdown:not(.secondary-list-item):nth-child(3) > a {
  color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Workaround CMS Styles by Class

1. Isolate and identify targets. Primary are last in line. Secondary are Primary's ancestors (i.e. parents, parent's parent (grandma), etc.)

   - Primary Targets

     - > Product #1 to #3: `li.header-navigation-list-item.secondary-list-item`
   - Secondary Targets

     - > Products: `li.header-navigation-list-item.has-dropdown` (Grandma)
     - > [Secondary List]: `ul.header-navigation-list.secondary-list`(Mom)
2. Determine what classes they all have in common. Find out what the style properties they have. These classes are untouchable because they are universally shared with every `<ul>` and `<li>`.

   - > All `<ul>` have `.header-navigation-list`
     >
     > - `ul.header-navigation-list {background: black; color: yellow;}`✱
   - > All `<li>` have `.header-navigation-list-item`
     >
     > - `li.header-navigation-list-item` no assignment it inherits instead ✱

   ✱ I have no idea what the styles are I arbitrarily assigned them.
3. Determine unique classes or secondary classes that are not shared with every `<ul>` or `<li>`

   - Primary Targets

     - > Product #1 to #3: `.secondary-list-item`
   - Secondary Targets

     - > Products: `.has-dropdown`
     - > [Secondary List]: `.secondary-list`

   That looks like 3 hooks all ready.
4. Given that we have no idea what the real situation is like the surrounding layout, all of the stylesheets, plugins, etc. Remember, navigation list layouts almost always have each anchor as an only child with the exception of a dropdown anchor (i.e. `li.has-dropdown > a.primary-link`), so it's easier to target the `<li>` first then step down to the anchor's level. Because inheritance, you should always style ancestors first then specifically style the children to override inherited styles. The possible selectors could be:

   > `li.has-dropdown > a.primary-link { color:red; font-size:48px; }`
   >
   > `li.has-dropdown > ul > li > a { color: yellow; font-size:48px; }`
5. If you still have problems, go back to step 2 and counter-style those universal classes:

   - If you find this:

     > `ul.header-navigation-list {background: black; color: yellow;}`
   - Counter style it:

     > `ul.header-navigation-list.secondary-list {background:none; color:transparent; }`
     >   `li.header-navigation-list-item.secondary-list-item > a { background: white; color:blue; }`